# Embedding YouTube video in WP8.1 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview

I am using WebView element to go to a video in youtube inside my WP8.1 app, I am trying to make the WebView go directly to a full screen mode. I have tried to use iframe as an html string, but it gives me a desktop like player, which is not convenient in a mobile app, any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try use [mytoolkit](http://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube) for your problem. With this library you can get video link and set it to `MediaElement`.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be more specific add [MyToolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyToolkit) and [MyToolkit.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyToolkit.Extended/) from nuget package manager.

Now in XAML page add:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Nameofelement" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" AutoPlay="False" Tapped="Nameofelement_Tapped" Height="320" Width="400"/>
```

In the .cs page add:

```
using MyToolkit.Multimedia;

 private async void Nameofelemnet_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("YoutubeID", YouTubeQuality.Quality360P);
       Name.Source = url.Uri;
       hello = 1;
    }
```

AretransportControlsEnabled="True" will itself add fullscreen and play, pause options.

Comment: there is a problem with the media element, it currently does not stream from youtube, it usd to but it stopped since few weeks, thats why I am trying to use webview and modify it to play the video in a full screen